# How to preparse JSON results in Retrofit2 (before sending to GsonConverterFactory)

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to consume a JSON using retrofit2 and GSON.

The following is the response provided by the server. Note that the value of "d" is a string of a valid JSON (once the slashes are removed).

> {"d": **"**[{\"Number\":\"2121\",\"NumberOfAppearances\":2,\"Prizes\":
>   [{\"DrawDate\":\"\/Date(1439654400000)\/\",\"PrizeCode\":\"S\"}, 
>       {\"DrawDate\":\"\/Date(874771200000)\/\",\"PrizeCode\":\"S\"}]}]**"**}

Is there a way to use retrofit2 to preparse the the json during the call to retrofitService to get the objects inside the value of d?

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            //is there anything i can do here to do preparsing of the results?
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();  

IQueryLocations = retrofit.create(IMyQuery.class);

//currently GsonResults is the string value of d, instead of the JSON objects
Call<GsonResult> result = IMyQuery.doQuery("2121");
```

Ideally, I like to insert a method call before addConverterFactory to do the preparsing

the output of the preparsing method would be some thing like the following:

> {"d": [{"Number":"2121","NumberOfAppearances":2,"Prizes":
>        [{"DrawDate": 1439654400000,"PrizeCode":"S"}, 
>        {"DrawDate": 874771200000,"PrizeCode":"S"}]}]}

Comment: This is not possible to preparse the response as you don't have the response in start. So, the easiest way is to get the raw response from retrofit and then parse according to your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your ideal solution, but you can return a wrapper for the result data:

```
class WrappedGsonResult {
    private static final Gson GSON = new Gson();

    @SerializedName("d")
    private String data;

    GsonResult() {}

    public GsonResult getData() {
        return GSON.fromJson(this.data, GsonResult.class);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Call<WrappedGsonResult> result = IMyQuery.doQuery("2121");
result.enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(final Call<WrappedGsonResult> call, final Response<WrappedGsonResult> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            GsonResult result = response.body().getData();
            // ...
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }

    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To exclude double quotes, you need to use `excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()` provided by `GsonBuilder`.

For example:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            // Add Gson object
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation` does: `"Configures Gson to exclude all fields from consideration for serialization or deserialization that do not have the Expose annotation"` which has nothing to do with quotes.